# Issue deleting instances with google API Explorer

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-api-java-client, google-apis-explorer

I have tried deleting instances using https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/instanceGroupManagers/deleteInstances but it's not working.

In the request body, I am entering

```
{
  "instances": [
    "scaler-group-instance-1"
  ]
}
```

For project, I used `project-name-1`

For zone, I used `us-west1-a`

For instanceGroupManager I am using `scaling-group-manager`

In response, I am receiving

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid value for field 'instances[0]': 'scaler-group-instance-1'. The URL is malformed.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid value for field 'instances[0]': 'scaler-group-instance-1'. The URL is malformed."
}
```

I have also tried this in Java as well using this code snippet and have also received a **400 Bad Request**

```
String projectId = "project-name-1";
String zoneName = "us-west1-a";
String instanceGroupName = "scaling-group-manager";
List<String> instancesToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
instancesToDelete.add("scaler-group-instance-1");
InstanceGroupManagersDeleteInstancesRequest deleteInstancesRequest = new InstanceGroupManagersDeleteInstancesRequest().setInstances(instancesToDelete);
Compute.InstanceGroupManagers.DeleteInstances deleteInstances = compute.instanceGroupManagers().deleteInstances(projectId, zoneName, instanceGroupName, deleteInstancesRequest).execute();
```

Is there something wrong with my request that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. This request expects the instance string to be a URL and not an instance name.

The instance can be found in the `selfLink` value in the listInstances requests.

Entering the selfLink URL into the request caused the server to reply correctly.